# create a table of values for a Fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis

```
SQF = FourierTrigSeries[SquareWave[t2a], t2a, 3, 
  FourierParameters -> {1, 2000 \[Pi]}]
     Plot[{SQF}, {t2a, 0, 0.003}, Exclusions -> None]
   data1 = Table[N[SQF], 5]
```

SQF can be plotted but the table did not evaluate t2a,
and I don't know how to have t2a evaluate so that data1
is a table of numerical values

Comment: Take a look at the explanations of `Table` in the documentation, try `Table[SQF /. t2a -> x, {x, 0, 0.003, 0.003/50}]`

Answer (score 1):

```
SQF = FourierTrigSeries[SquareWave[t2a], t2a, 3, 
  FourierParameters -> {1, 2000 π}]

Plot[SQF, {t2a, 0, 0.003}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
data = Table[SQF, {t2a, 0, 0.003, 0.00001}];

ListPlot[data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Both approaches works, thanks, Regards, Philip